# ERROR from PowerShell - ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive:

Tags: powershell

I've seen many post and researched to no avail.  I did not write this script initially and was told it was working fine until being moved to another network location.  I will share complete script.

it connects to an input file where provider id's are entered, connects to a website API to retrieve names, address, phone number of those providers, then writes that information back to an output file.

I would sincerely appreciate any help with this.

This is the error:

```
At G:\somepath\NPI Search\NPI.ps1:42 char:18
+ ...        $NPI_Results = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $Response.Content
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Version Info:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2364
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2364
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Below this is the complete script

---

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

$INPUT_FILE = "$($scriptDir)\input.csv"
$OUTPUT_FILE = "$($scriptDir)\results.csv"
$API_URL = "https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/resultsDemo2/"
$NPI_PATTERN = "^\d{10}$"
$result = @{}

Write-Host "NPI Resolver v1.0`n`n"
Write-Host "[STATUS] Attempting to read NPI Numbers from $($INPUT_FILE)."
try {
    $input = Get-Content -LiteralPath $INPUT_FILE
} catch {
    Write-Host "`n[!!ERROR!!] Unable to open input.csv. Please ensure it is in the same directory as this program.`n"
    exit 1
}
Write-Host "`n[STATUS] Success!`n"
# Write header
$output = "NPI NUMBER,RESULT,LAST UPDATE,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CREDENTIAL,STATUS,ADDRESS 1 LABEL, ADDRESS 1,TELEPHONE 1,ADDRESS 2 LABEL,ADDRESS 2,TELEPHONE 2`n"
# Iterate through each line in input.csv
foreach ($line in $input) {
    # Check if line is a 10 digit number, if not ignore the line
    if ($line -match $NPI_PATTERN) {
        try {
            Write-Host "[STATUS] Requesting results for $($line)..."
            $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$($API_URL)?number=$($line)&enumeration_type=&taxonomy_description=&first_name=&last_name=&organization_name=&address_purpose=&city=&state=&postal_code=&country_code=&limit=&skip="
        } catch {
            Write-Host "`n[!!ERROR!!] Error communicating with $($API_URL)`n"
            exit 1
        }
        # Interpret JSON results
        
        $NPI_Results = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $Response.Content
        
        # Check if a result was found
        if ($NPI_Results.result_count -eq "1") {
            $output = $output + "$($NPI_Results.results.number),SUCCESS,$($NPI_RESULTS.results.basic.last_updated),$($NPI_RESULTS.results.basic.name),`"$($NPI_RESULTS.results.taxonomies.desc)`",$($NPI_RESULTS.results.basic.credential),$($NPI_RESULTS.results.basic.status)"
            foreach ($address in $NPI_Results.results.addresses) {
                $output = $output + ",$($address.address_purpose),`"$($address.address_1), $($address.address_2), $($address.city), $($address.state), $($address.postal_code), $($address.country_code)`",$($address.telephone_number)"
            }
        } else {
            $output = $output + "$($line),NONE"
        }
        $output = $output + "`n"
    }
}
# Save results
try {
    $output | Out-File -LiteralPath $OUTPUT_FILE
} catch {
    Write-Host "`n[!!ERROR!!] Unable to save results.csv. Please close the file if you have it open already and re-run.`n"
    exit 1
}
Write-Host "`n[STATUS] Complete! Check results in $($OUTPUT_File).`n"
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$Response.Content` is JSON, and is properly formatted?

Comment: I am not sure of that and I don't know how to check that.  I am familiar with PowerShell but this is beyond my expertise.  This is the original script that someone else wrote.  I was told it was working up until the time it was moved to a new network location.  Had our Cyber Security team confirm that I could run the script from new location with no permissions issues, I was assured that I could run it.

Comment: I did assign execution policy.  Prior to me doing that I couldn't run the script at all.  Afterward, I could, then received the error I'm asking about.          Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
 LocalMachine       AllSigned

Comment: I would run the script line by line to the `ForEach($line in $input)` line and do `$line = $input|?{$_ -match $NPI_PATTERN}|Select -first 1` instead, then run the `$Response =` line, and check `$Response.content`. Run it through a JSON validator like https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: A practical way of debuging a script like this, could be [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) it (meaning run it in the scope of the console): `. G:\somepath\NPI Search\NPI.ps1` (note the extra dot is front of the path) and after it failed check what's in `$Response.content`

Comment: @ClintGuillory - per TheMadTechnician, if you add the line ```$Response.Contnet | Out-File -Path "C:\temp\response.txt"``` to your script above the line ```$NPI_Results = ConvertFrom-Json ...``` it will dump the response out to disk and you can check if it's valid json or not. I've seen issues before where moving a task to a different server causes the internal corporate web proxy to return an "Access Denied" message due to firewall rules being allow-listed for the original server but not the new one - you might be having something similar...

Comment: @mclayton - I contacted our Cyber Security team to verify if it needed permissions on the new location, I was told I had necessary permissions to run it.  I will however take yours and TheMadTechicians advice on debugging.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: @mclayton - I added the line you told me to and the output looks like a bunch of html. Font names and font size info.  It's too much to copy and paste into a comment.  I ran it through a json parser online as TheMadTechnician suggested.  Results - Error: Parse error on line 1:
< !DOCTYPE html > < 
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: If it's html then a json parser will definitely fail to parse it :-). Try opening the file in a web browser and see what it says. You might have to give the file a *.htm extension first (e.g. response.htm)...

Comment: @mclayton changed file to htm and opened in Chrome, it's just a title 'NPPES NPI Registry'  Which is the website it's trying to get provider information from.

Comment: My only other suggestions are to try it again on the old server and check it still works, or manually hit the generated uri in a browser on the new server with one of the values from your csv and see what that gives. There's possibly too many local variables to be able to diagnose it remotely...